# What's the point of aiming for god at old age?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, vedic-gods

If someone is a criminal or a bad person in his youth or teen and claims no god came to correct me i has no info about god in such a young age my house conditions were not good or some other reason and now is aiming for god at old age. Is this what God wants?

Answer (score 2):

If a person says to himself that he is bad; bad he will remain. If that same person says to himself that he is a good, he will become a good person. The *Astavakra Samhita* (Swami Nityaswarupananda translator) says in verse 1.11:

> He who considers himself free is free indeed, and he who considers himself bound remains bound. 'As one thinks, so one becomes' is a popular saying in this world, and it is quite true.

The journey from Delhi to Kolkata only starts when you take the first step. The more steps you take the closer Kolkata becomes and the farther away Delhi becomes. But you must start the walk.

Sri Krishna says in *Gita* 8.5 (Swami Niklhilananda translator):

> And whoso at the time of death, leaves his body remembering Me alone goes forth--he attains My being; concerning this there is no doubt.

and 9.22:

> Those persons who worship Me, meditating on their identity with Me and ever devoted to Me--to them I carry what they lack and for them I preserve what they already have.

and 18.58:

> Fixing your heart on Me, you will overcome every difficulty by My grace; but if from self-conceit you do not listen to Me, you shall perish utterly.

Finally, remember how Sri Krishna addresses Arjuna at the very start of the *Gita* at the beginning of Chapter 2.2-3:

> *The Lord said*: In this crisis, O Arjuna, whence comes such lowness of spirit, unbecoming of an Aryan, dishonorable, and an obstacle to the attaining of heaven?
>
> **Do not yield to unmanliness, O son of Pritha. It does not become you.** **Shake off this base faint-heartedness and arise, O scorcher of enemies!**

As the Upanishad says: Awake, Arise! Stop not till the Goal is reached!